# Android Circular Button Among Four Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I searched out a lots of materials online but did not find any help full resource for such button design although i am able to round the corner or make the button circular but i failed to draw the following GUI design..any one have any idea how to do this or it would be better how to curved the button toward inside instead of making it circular..thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the layout I've made. It shoud be improved, but the basic problem is solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circular"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background = "@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background = "@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background = "@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:background = "@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:text="Button" />
    </GridLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the circular shape used for the central button background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<stroke
    android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:width="3dp"/>
<size
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: FrameLayout is more efficient than RelativeLayout. Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the center button.

Comment: But sir there comes an issue when i change the API level into 19 then the center  button hide behind the four buttons.when change back to API level greater than 19 then layout looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use framelayout for adding that five button .
beacause of framelayout you can overlap the roundcirle on top of view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dell.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="293dp"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="297dp"
            android:layout_height="159dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Button5" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't put RelativeLayout as root. It's inefficient. And it has only one child in this case so it's useless anyway (and Android Studio will tell you this).